# change value of specific keys of an object

Tags: javascript

lets assume i have the following object and I need to format only the keys of a and b and multiple them by 2. how can I do this? should I make a copy of the object?
i have 8 keys that need to be changed so please try to find a short and efficient solution

```
const ob = {
a:1,
b:2,
c:3,
d:4
}
```

Comment: `const newObject = {...ob, a: ob.a *2, b: ob.b * 2}`

Comment: is there a better way? i have 8 keys that need to be changed

Comment: "better way" he said, I dare you to calculate the bigO notation of that expression. Code won't write down by itself. With all respect sir. I recommend you to read the how to ask a question. Blog of stack overflow

Comment: @Ernesto Calm down man. By "better way" OP means easier to write, consider he has to change multiple properties, not just two. It is impractical to write ` * 2` a hundred times if there are a hundred fields to change. OP is not saying about the performance.

Answer (score 1):

A more optimized or shorter way in case if you have more keys, would be:

```
const ob = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
};
const keysToChange = ['a', 'b'];

console.log(ob);

keysToChange.forEach(key => {
  if (ob[key]) {
    ob[key] = ob[key] * 2;
  }
});

console.log(ob);
```

Comment: You foreach all array for change two value, i don't see all this "optimized"

Comment: Aah thanks for pointing that out, made a small change ;) now iterating on keysToChange

Comment: Why are you checking `keysToChange.includes(key)`. It will always be true because you are iterating in the same array. You are just making it inefficient

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you need to changes many keys. You may consider this way

```js
const ob = {
  a:1,
  b:2,
  c:3,
  d:4,
  e:5,
  f:6,
  g:7,
  h:8,
  i:9,
  j:10,
  k:11,
  l:12,
  m:13,
  n:14,
  o:15
}

const keysToChange = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"];
for(let key of keysToChange)
{
  ob[key] = ob[key] * 2;
}
console.log(ob);
```

Comment: I've just written the same solution. Nice one. Short, descriptive, easy to understand and maintainable

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually like that

```js
const ob = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
};
console.log(ob);
ob['a'] = ob['a'] * 2;
ob['b'] = ob['b'] * 2;
console.log(ob);
```

Comment: I know this method but its for very few changes. what happens if you need to this for 8 keys. duplicate code for no reason

Comment: If you haven't a logic(or didn't tell us) how you can automate this process?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Objects</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Create an object:
const ob = {
  a:1,
b:2,
c:3,
d:4
};

ob.a=ob.a*2;
ob.b=ob.b*2;


document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
ob.a + "  " + ob.b ;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already knows keys which you must update you can store them in an array and loop through that array and for each key update the related key in the object.

```js
const ob = {
  a:1,
  b:2,
  c:3,
  d:4
};

let updatedKeys = ['a', 'b'];

updatedKeys.forEach(key => {
  if(Object.keys(ob).indexOf(key) !== -1) {
      ob[key] *= 2;
  }
});

console.log(ob);
```

Comment: `ob` is not an array but on Object

Comment: as `ob` is an object then you can directly get value using `key` so no need to use `Object.keys` and then `indexOf`. Just use `ob[key]`. Earlier same comment had a TYPO

Comment: It checking if the existence of the key before performing the update. That's the reason for `Object.keys(obj).indexOf(key)` If I try to update the key which doesn't exists It will return **NaN**

Answer (score 0):

If you want the original object and the new object then proceed as follow

```js
const ob = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
};

console.log(ob);

let new_obj = {};           
Object.assign(new_obj, ob);//copy the original object to the new object
//change the value of new keys one by one
new_obj['a'] = new_obj['a'] * 2;
new_obj['b'] = new_obj['b'] * 2;

console.log(new_obj);

//alternatively if you want to loop through all keys and change values for keys 'a' and 'b', proceed as follows:

for(key in new_obj) {
    if(key=='a' || key =='b'){
        new_obj[key] = new_obj[key] * 2;
    }    
}

console.log(new_obj);
```